# Copy selected option from one droplist to another

Tags: javascript, copy

I have two drop-lists to let user select the month with the same code :

```
   <select id="Month1" name="Month1" >
     <option>Month</option>
     <option>January</option>
           so on ...
    </select>


   <select id="Month2" name="Month2" >
     <option>Month</option>
     <option>January</option>
           so on ...
    </select>
```

first list id is "Month1" , second list id is "Month2"

What I want is : when a user select a month from the first list (onclick) the second list automatically selects the same ..in other words 1st list onclick action sends the month selected to be selected also in the 2nd list ..

Comment: Do you want solution javascript only or jQuery will be OK for you?

Comment: Please try out AngularJS for all these kinds of activities. It absolutely rocks...

Comment: Javascript solution would be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: **http://jsfiddle.net/NY2UL/**

```
<select id="Month1" name="Month1" onchange="document.getElementById('Month2').value=this.value">
    <option>Month</option>
    <option>January</option>
    so on ...
</select>


<select id="Month2" name="Month2" onchange="document.getElementById('Month1').value=this.value">
    <option>Month</option>
    <option>January</option>
    so on ...
</select>
```

Comment: @user3132629 you should also add values to your option tags.  Example: `<option value="January">January</option>`

Comment: @gfrobenius - not needed, if the value is omitted, the options text is used as the selects value by default.

Comment: @Noctis - You need to learn to read, there's no way to do this without javascript.

Comment: @adeneo - as in, no extra scripts in the file / fiddle.

Comment: @adeneo - dunno. I'm a c# fanboy really ... but enough idle chatter ... you can open a chat if you want to lecture me on onlining js :)

Comment: Thanks gfrobenius .. this was a simple and professional way too - I used <option value="xxxx">xxxx</option> :)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 $('#Month1').on("change",function() {      
      $("#Month2 option[text="+$('#Month1').val()+"]").attr("selected","selected");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="whatever">
    <select id="Month1" name="Month1">
        <option>Jan</option><option>Feb</option></select>
    <select id="Month2" name="Month2">
        <option>Jan</option><option>Feb</option></select>
</form>
```

If they're in a form with an ID, you can do it like this:

```
document.forms.whatever.Month1.onchange = function () {
    this.form.Month2.value = this.value;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/42FfK/

**Edit**

If you want to be extra lazy and use inline event event handlers like in the answer you selected, you might as well skip `getElementById`:

```
<form>
    <select id="Month1" name="Month1" onchange="Month2.value = this.value">
        <option>Jan</option><option>Feb</option></select>
    <select id="Month2" name="Month2">
        <option>Jan</option><option>Feb</option></select>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/42FfK/1/

Comment: They must be in the same form ?

Comment: @user3132629, two separate examples